# Calling class from same file with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this peace of code I designed but the problem is that I'm not good enough with calling a class back so that I can get the generated number without typing it back. Code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import tkFont
import re

class Questionnaire(Frame):
def __init__(self, master):


    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    root.title("Survey")
    self.grid()
    self.createQuestHealth()




def createQuestHealth(self):
     studentNumber: float(102.02)
```

Here I want to call this number automatically without initializing a new number with new variable. I tried by:

```
one = Questionnaire()
val = one.get()
```

but it says :

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I didn't get that at all ><

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__` constructor for `Questionnaire` takes two arguments, `self` and `master`. When you make an instance of your class `one = Questionnaire()`, self is automatically assigned the the instance, but `muster` is missing. You should provide master/parent widget for your class. For example.

```
root = Tk()
one = Questionnaire(root)
```